# react-native run-ios without build

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

How can I run the application without rebuilding the project (of course the app is installed on the relevant simulator from previous run)

I run the application on iOS (for instance) like this:

`react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone 8'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [this post](https://medium.com/xcblog/simctl-control-ios-simulators-from-command-line-78b9006a20dc), I found this command:

`xcrun simctl launch booted <APP_BUNDLE_ID>`

It will launch the application which pre-installed on the current running simulator (if we have 2 or more simulators running simultaneously, we will need to pick one by its simulator ID).

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you're trying to do. If you just need to reload, then you can do it through the developer menu as @Kraylog says. Or via `⌘R` if the application is already open and running.

If you've closed packager/metro bundler, then you'll want to start that with `react-native start`. You should then be able to just click the app icon in the simulator to run it + reloading as stated above as needed.

Comment: Thanks, I need command line tool/commnad (or part of `react-native-cli`) to run the app without build it.